# Google Maps API v3 - API Script Compression / Obfuscation

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, compression, obfuscation

I've worked a lot with v3 recently, and if you noticed, beside usual compression that is done on scripts (local variable renaming, white space removal, etc.), the API script is pushed forward on this, and also has classes and their methods renamed with 2 character names. Also I've noticed other 'strange' things, like the names that are exposed to the API users are stored as variables and used inside the script. In my opinion, I think there is also some sort of obfuscation intended.

Don't know if I made myself clear, or if this is some sort of compression that I didn't get right, but I think you get the point.

I'm interested if someone knows if this is something like a public utility that compresses scripts in such a way, or if someone could point out some references that might help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that Google uses their Closure Compiler - it does much of what you describe.
[Google Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/)

CC is much more ambitious (and rewarding) than other tools like yui-compressor or jsmin

Comment: Correct, the Maps API uses the Closure compiler.

Comment: I thought about that. I'm aware of the Closure Compiler although I never used it, but I was curious because I saw some behaviours that seemed somewhat unusual, that I didn't find (or thought I didn't find) in the CC. But now that you told me, I'm going to 'investigate' further, thanks!